# AWS Datapipeline incorrect java version

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline, data-pipeline, aws-data-pipeline

I am trying to execute a jar file in my datapipeline and it is erroring out in a fashion that indicates to me that the version of java that is installed in my pipeline is lower than that required by the executable jar. I have tried to add a command to update the java version as the first command in my shell command activity but the activity errors out with the message 'S3 Path must begin with prefix s3://'. So, how can I go about upgrading my java version to 1.8 in my pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

## Update

I created a bandaid solution as well as a more long term solution for this problem. The bandaid was to have a shell script that would install openjdk 1.8 and remove openjdk 1.7 then run the java program. The long term solution is to create a custom AMI that has those two steps in the init script.

Comment: could you post the script you used?